# Window.Open() incorrectly escaped?

Tags: javascript, parameters, escaping, window.open

I'm a relatively light JavaScript user, so this minor operation is giving me some major grief -- I'm sure I'm missing something.

All I want is a popup to open, passing one value -- the emplogin, a string variable called getEmp -- to a bog-standard .php page thusly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getEmployeeInfo(getEmp)
{
window.open ("../Pages/Employee_Info.php?emplogin=" + getEmp + ",\"mywin\",\"menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=450\"");
}
</script>
```

And it works... sort of.  Testing the result by looking at the resulting $_REQUEST object shows me that the page is receiving the $emplogin as

```
Array
(
    [emplogin] =>JohnDoe,"mywin","menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=450"
)
```

IOW, the second and third parameters for Window.Open() are being passed along as part of the $emplogin received by PHP, instead of being parsed by JavaScript! (I'm using 'echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($_REQUEST, true));')

I'm sure there's something I'm not doing right with the escaping of the parameters but I haven't been able to hit on the right search terms.  Thank you for any and all guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getEmployeeInfo(getEmp)
{
    window.open ("../Pages/Employee_Info.php?emplogin=" + getEmp, "mywin", "menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=450");
}
</script>
```

Comment: It made me wait ten minutes!  I guess even the system didn't believe this would be answered so fast. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're including your second and third parameters as part of your URL string, so it's all being treated as one single parameter.

What you want is:
`window.open ("../Pages/Employee_Info.php?emplogin=" + getEmp,"mywin","menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=450");`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation -- I think I got so worried about using the string parameter correctly that I somehow assumed that I needed to feed the entirety of the commands in as a damn string!

Answer (score 0):

That is how it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getEmployeeInfo(getEmp)
{
window.open ("../Pages/Employee_Info.php?emplogin=" + getEmp + ,"mywin","menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=600,height=450");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

urlencode your variable and remove the escaping of your other parameters in the open command